# How to assign the parameter value of a string read from a text file in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there an approach in system Verilog or Verilog , using which one can replace string instances with its value. To explain in details, I will provide an example.
Lets say we have some fixed register address which you define as a parameter like

```
parameter L1 = 3'b000;
parameter L2 = 3'b010;
```

Now have a command file in which I give L2 as a string on one line and read this using fscanf in Verilog. Is it possible to get value 3'b010 instead of L2 when I do

```
location = L2
```

input file structure

```
let L2 set some_value
```

Comment: Add the command you want to execute and the expected output.. It is not very clear what you are asking for.

Comment: No, verilog does not allow this. You need a way to generate a verilog statement via a different app.

Answer (score 0):

This is one use of an associative array with a string index.

```
bit [2:0] map[string] ='{
   "L1": 3'b000,
   "L2": 3'b010
};

string rename = "L2";

location = map[regname];
```

There are a number of packages out there to help you split a command line into separate strings variables. One example from svLib: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Uk

Comment: Hey dave_59, thanks for the reply, I think my question was a little confusing. Let me explain the scenario. 
```
1. I have a text file which has some commands that I want to pass to a verilog file.
2. I have a part of text which I have already tokenized.
3. The 2nd token in the text is the name of a register which I have declared as a parameter
4. When I compile my code, I want the simulator to take in the value of the parameter and not the parameter name.
```

Comment: I actually got it to work using the following approach below, not sure if its optimum, but it does what I need.

Comment: Either approach can work depending on what your other needs are and the ability to maintain the code. (i.e. how often and in how many other places you need to perform this translation.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through a series of experiments and figured out a way, I don't know if this is the optimum way to do it, but I think, it gets the work done.
I started a case statement  and compared the string value for each parameter value and assigned the value of the string parameter inside it. for e.g.

```
case(second_token)
"L2":
    location = 3'b010;
"L1":
   location = 3'b000;
endcase
```

so now when I want to use L1 value, I could use location value wherever L1 reg needs to be acessed